# GUI program stuck

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am designing a GUI (the GUI itself is in a separate class called mainGUI). The GUI has 2 buttons.  Each button sets `main.subProgramNumber` to 1 or 2 (depending on the button), sets `main.safeToContinue` to false, then disposes the GUI using `dispose()`.  But when I click the button within the GUI the GUI closes then nothing happens.

When I test this with the debugger it behaves differently than when I run the program normally. When using the debug tool the GUI remains open after I click the button and loads forever.

Here is my main code

```java
 genData main = new genData();
 main.safeToContinue = false;
 main.running = true;
     
 while(main.running == true){
        
        //trigger GUI    
        mainGUI MG = new mainGUI();
        MG.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        MG.setSize(250, 275);
        MG.setVisible(true);
       
        //wait tell the GUI says its safe to continue
        while(main.safeToContinue == false){
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(mainGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
               
        //check if main.subProgram is 1
        if(main.subProgramNumber == 1){
            System.out.println("subProgram = 1");
        }
                
        //check if main.subProgram is 2
        if(main.subProgramNumber == 2){
           System.out.println("subProgram = 2");
        }

            
}
```

below is a simplified version of my GUI code. (sorry, it's kind of a lot of code, but I couldn't figure out how to make it simpler than this...)

```java
public class mainGUI extends JFrame{
    
    public JButton add;
    public JButton remove;
    public JButton edit;
    public JButton report;
    public JButton close;
    
    public mainGUI(){
        super("Guest Manager");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        add = new JButton("Add a Guest");
        remove = new JButton("Remove a Guest");
        close = new JButton("Close");
        
        add(add);
        add(remove);
        add(close);
        
        addGuest ag = new addGuest();
        add.addActionListener(ag);
        
        removeGuest rg = new removeGuest();
        remove.addActionListener(rg);
        
        Close c = new Close();
        close.addActionListener(c);
        
    }
    
    private class addGuest implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            genData main = new genData();
            main.subProgramNumber = 1; 
            main.safeToContinue = true;
            dispose();
        }
    }
    
    private class removeGuest implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            genData main = new genData();
            main.subProgramNumber = 2;  
            main.safeToContinue = true;
            dispose();
        }
    }
    
    private class Close implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            
            genData main = new genData();
            main.safeToContinue = true;
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

below is a requested, woking, example of a technique I have used (and am using above)

the main program (this is called when i click start):

```java
 varData MC = new varData();
        do{
            
            MC.safeToContinue = false;
            
            //open and run the main GUI
            ExerciseMainGUI EM = new ExerciseMainGUI();
            EM.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            EM.setSize(250, 275);
            EM.setVisible(true);

            //System.out.println("debug 1");
            
            //wait tell the sub program closes to continue
            do{
                hutLib.pause(1);
            }while(MC.safeToContinue==false);
            
            hutLib.pause(1);
            
        }while(MC.running == true);
```

the GUI I call above:

```java
public class ExerciseMainGUI extends JFrame{
    
    private JButton bottlePacker;
    private JButton triangleTester;
    private JButton primeChecker;
    private JButton averager;
    private JButton rollTheDice;
    private JButton close;
    
    public ExerciseMainGUI(){
        super("Java Exercises");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        bottlePacker = new JButton("   Bottle Packer   ");
        triangleTester = new JButton("  Triangle Tester  ");
        primeChecker = new JButton("   Prime Checker   ");
        averager = new JButton ("Averager (offline)");
        rollTheDice = new JButton("Roll the Dice (offline)");
        close = new JButton("       Close       ");
        
        add(bottlePacker);
        add(triangleTester);
        add(primeChecker);
        add(averager);
        add(rollTheDice);
        add(close);
        
        bottlePacker bp = new bottlePacker();
        bottlePacker.addActionListener(bp);
        
        triangleTester tt = new triangleTester();
        triangleTester.addActionListener(tt);
        
        primeChecker pc = new primeChecker();
        primeChecker.addActionListener(pc);
        
        averager a = new averager();
        averager.addActionListener(a);
        
        rollTheDice rtd = new rollTheDice();
        rollTheDice.addActionListener(rtd);
        
        close c = new close();
        close.addActionListener(c);
    }
    
    private class bottlePacker implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            //runs a subprogram
            
        }
    }
    
    private class triangleTester implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            //runs a subprogram
        }
    }
    
    private class primeChecker implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            //runs a subprogram
            
        }
    }
    
    private class averager implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            //runs a subprogram
            
        }
    }
    
    private class rollTheDice implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            //runs a subprogram
            
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NOTE: Roll the Dice will run in the command line.");
            
            //oldCodeStorage.rollTheDice.rollTheDice();
            
        }
    }
    
    private class close implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            varData MC = new varData();
            MC.running = false;
            MC.safeToContinue = true;
            
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: when each subprogram is finished it rund the below code:

```java
varData MC = new varData();
MC.safeToContinue = true;
```

I know this is a lot but I was explicitly asked to post it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212233/discussion-on-question-by-hutonahill-gui-program-stuck).

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing Swing components here. You should show your app and react to events via event listeners. This requires no loops etc.

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JButton b1 = new JButton("Action 1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Action 2");
        b1.addActionListener((e)->System.out.println("Action 1 taken")); // your subcommand 1 
        b2.addActionListener((e)->System.out.println("Action 2 taken")); //your subcomand 2
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.add(b2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Also remember to NOT to invoke expensive actions in `actionListeners` but to delegate those to background job - it will freeze your UI otherwise. Writing UI application in Swing is not as straightforward as you might think and requires a small set of basic knowledge (regarding Swing itself). It is not bad to try, but without familiarizing yourself with the basics of Swing, you will hit the wall gazillion of times more - trust me, I'v been there.

You have mentioned that you are new to threding - Swing itself is single threaded - but it involves threading to do various of tasks that would slow down the application or make it unresponsive otherwise.

I strongly suggest you start digging trough eg Oracle's Swing tutorials.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: I will edit my original post to include my GUI code. I think I am already doing this in a more lvl1-java-student sort of way.

Comment: @hutonahill level 1 java or not, you can still use java naming conventions. GenData vs genData. Also, a lvl 1 java student should understand the difference between a static variable and an instance variable.

Comment: not in my java class. we are almost through the semester and have touched on static vs instatic variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't modifying `main.safeToContinue` at all. That's why it's stuck in that infinite while loop

Comment: main.safeToContinue is being modified by the GUI as i said in the text above my code. I have tested and used this in several of my other projects. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have a class.

```
class GenData{
    static int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
}
```

Now I have two *instances* of that object.

```
GenData a = new GenData();
GenData b = new GenData();

a.x = 5;
a.y = 10;

System.out.println( b.x + ", " + b.y );
```

What do you expect the output to be?

b has it's own instance variables. So I expect the output to be.

> 5, 1

In your code you call `new genData()` that creates a new instance of the class. If your field is not static then it will not be shared with the version of genData you are checking.

Please also use java naming conventions. `GenData` is better for a class name.

How to fix.

```
public class mainGUI extends JFrame{

    public JButton add;
    public JButton remove;
    public JButton edit;
    public JButton report;
    public JButton close;
    genData main;
    public mainGUI(genData main){
        this.main = main;
        //don't change the rest.
    }

    private class addGuest implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //genData main = new genData();
            //don't call new here, use the reference you 
            //received.
        }
    }

}
```